# Drawing balls from urn with unequal probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics, random-variables

Consider an urn that has $n$ numbered balls such that the probability of drawing ball $i$ is $p_i$. We keep drawing balls from the urn with replacement until we have seen all the balls. What is the probability that the ball numbered $n$ is the last ball to be drawn i.e when ball $n$ is drawn, we have already seen all balls from $1$ to $n-1$.

My approach : I tried simluations of this in java with small numbers and the answer seems to $1/n$. To solve this problem formally, I tried to apply the chain rule so if $A_i$ is the event of seeing ball $i$, then we want to calculate $P(A_i | A_1,..,A_{i-1})$ (this is a geometric distribution with probability $1/p_i$) but I don't know how to condition this on all possible orderings of $A_1,..,A_{i-1}$

Edit : My answer was coming as $1 \over n$ because $p_i = {1 \over n}$. So the simulation was wrong.

Comment: @PatrickStevens can you elaborate? I did not understand.

Comment: What are exactly the $p_i$'s.Are they the probabilities that you draw the $i^{th}$ ball at the first draw? Do these probabilities change draw by draw?

Comment: @zoli $p_i$ is the probability of drawing the ball $i$ from the urn at any stage. They do not change every draw. I also forgot to mention that we draw balls with replacement (added to question).

Comment: But that can include balls that are numbered higher than $i$ and can potentially include ball $n$ which is not what we want. [The question (which is now deleted) was to consider $1-p_i$]

Comment: For *general* $p_i$, the answer cannot be $\frac{1}{n}$. For if $p_n$ is close to $1$, it is very unlikely that ball $n$ is the last one to be seen, while if $p_n$ is much smaller than the other $p_i$, ball $n$ being last becomes much more likely. (If all the $p_i$ are equal, it is clear by symmetry that the probability is $1/n$.)

Comment: @AndréNicolas Is there a way I can formalize this i.e to show that if $p_n$ is larger than all $p_i$, then the probability is lesser than $1 \over n$?

Comment: Probably. I have not really looked at the problem, there may be a not difficult expression for the probabilities. The comment above was just to point out that $1/n$ cannot be right in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get an idea for what the answer looks like by working it out for $n=3$ and $n=4$. For $n=3$, either you first draw ball $1$ and then have to draw ball $2$ before ball $3$, or you first draw ball $2$ and then have to draw ball $1$ before ball $3$:

$$
p_1\cdot\frac{p_2}{p_2+p_3}+p_2\cdot\frac{p_1}{p_1+p_3}=p_1p_2\left(\frac1{p_2+p_3}+\frac1{p_1+p_3}\right)\;.
$$

I don't see how to express the general result more succinctly than this:

$$
\left(\prod_{k=1}^np_k\right)\sum_{\sigma\in S_{n-1}}\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(1-\sum_{j=1}^kp_{\sigma(j)}\right)^{-1}\;.
$$